# Why Won't Soulcraft Synchronize My Game?

Tags: windows-8, soulcraft

I recently got Soulcraft for my Windows 8 laptop. After playing for a bit, I decided to create an account. It will not synchronize and I can't sign up. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing out of the game and signing back in, it let me save.